# Joomshopping. Передать параметры из JQ в php

Tags: php, jquery

Мне надо передать параметры из JQ в  php по средствам ajax.
JQ code пример:

```
  function addAccardion(){

    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    if (screenWidth < 769) {

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "product_default.php",//карточка товаров  
        data :{width:screenWidth}

          }); 

 }           
}
```

Жду ответ в php

```
<?php echo $_POST['width']?>
```

В чем может быть ошибка? я не получаю данные и нет ошибок нигде.
Мне надо в их считать в файле product_default.php это файл какой отв. за полный вид товара

Comment: А где закрывающий знак для `if`?

Comment: это я скопировал просто так криво. так то все ест. UPD код!

Answer (score 0):

Сам не до конца понимаю, но у меня так получилось.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addAccardion();

  function addAccardion() {
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    if (screenWidth > 769) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '1.php',
        data: {
          width: screenWidth
        },
        success: function() {
          $('.info').text(screenWidth);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="info">
    <?php 
  echo (int)($_POST['width']);
 ?>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```